# Python idiom: If True do while True, if False do once

Tags: python, idioms

I'm looking for a good idiom to do the following: given a boolean variable called `retry`, if that variable is `True`, then run some sequence of instructions inside a `while True` loop, and if the variable is `False` then just run the sequence of instructions once.

The best I could come up with is:

```
while True:
    # my code
    if not retry:
        break
```

The problem I have with this is that `while True` is at the top and only at the end and inside the loop you see the logic. It's not very clear in my opinion.

Here's the straightforward one:

```
if retry:
    while True:
        # my code
else:
    # my code
```

But then you're duplicating code.

Another bad alternative with code duplication:

```
# my code
while retry:
    # my code
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The obvious solution would be a `do` / `while` loop, but Python doesn't have that, so ... *shrug*.